References on Cech cohomology
I'm currently working on my final degree project and I'm trying to learn about sheaf cohomology. I'm searching for references as an introduction to Cech cohomology and the firsts vanighing theorems of Grothendieck. If they could be with a bunch of examples it would be great.
Thank you all!

Gathmann's algebraic geometry notes contain some material on Cech cohomology.

@JoshuaTilley Thank you! I will give it a look :)

Chech cohomology is the sheaf cohomology with respect to a constant sheaf. Are you sure you mean it or you are actually asking about general sheaf cohomology? You can read about Chech cohomology for instance in the book of Eilenberg and Steenrod on algebraic topology.
